# Codecov commit status in GitHub not getting updated when yaml file is updated

Tags: codecov

I changed our CodeCov team yaml file to change the commit status in Github, as seen below.

**initial file:**

```
coverage:
  precision: 2   
  round: down
  status:
    project:
      default:
        target: 80%
```

**modified file:**

```
coverage:
  precision: 2   
  round: down
  status:
    project:
      default:
        threshold: 0.2%
```

then I created a pull a new pull request in GitHub, which kicks off the codecov project check, and the commit status was not updated with the threshold instead of the target (target should not show up anymore since it was removed).

here is a picture to see what I mean:
[image: commit status]

Any ideas why, when I update the team yaml, the changes do not appear in GH?  Does it simply take a while for the change to take effect?

I have tried resetting the webhook, clearing my internet cache, starting off a new pull request... to no avail

**Thanks!**